# How can I make these stacks generic?

Tags: java, generics, stack

I have the following simple method:

```
public static Stack transfer(Stack s) {  
    Stack t = new Stack();
    return t;
}
```

I intend to fill in more functionality, but I'd like to make this applicable to generic stacks:

```
Stack<E>
```

Where `E` is the generic type of the elements in the stack. I tried several ways to add the element to the `Stack`, but I seem to keep getting errors no matter how I have them set up.  I know this is a basic question, but I've never really used stacks before and I just need pointed in the right direction.

The code is in Java, using Eclipse.  Stacks are found in java.util.Stack

Comment: [Stack is already a generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

Comment: What is `s` used for?  By looking at what the function does, it should rather be called `createStack` and take no arguments.

Comment: It actually takes the input Stack and returns it reversed as the output Stack.  It was very simple to complete once the generics question was answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class is already generic, but in order make the `transfer` method generic, you have to do:

```
public static <E> Stack<E> transfer(Stack<E> s) {  
    Stack<E> t = new Stack<E>();
    return t;
}
```

Comment: That's all it took.  I was missing the E between static and stack.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to provide a type as type parameter to the already generic class `Stack<T>`

```
Stack<String> stringStack = new Stack<>();
```